# Java types and names

Tags: java

I have a [homework assignment](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dD4U1vTYKF1BRqRda08B4IwWxARZHTQNFk0vw-JEf7Q) in a Programming Languages course. This particular exercise is on names, nameables, hiding, overloading and polymorphic overloading.

I was given a confusing yet valid Java program (shown below), and what I need to do is for each occurrence of `Oompa_Loompa` in the program, classify its lexical role (variable name, class name, method name, etc.).
I'm having trouble with these occurences in particular:

- The ones in the line marked `/*A*/`
- `Oompa_Loompa` near `new` in the line marked `/*D*/`
- `Oompa_Loompa` near `super` in the line marked `/*B*/`
- `Oompa_Loompa` near the ternary `?` in the line marked `/*C*/`

Here is the code:

```
class Oompa_Loompa {
  Oompa_Loompa Oompa_Loompa; /*A*/
  <Oompa_Loompa> Oompa_Loompa() {}
  Oompa_Loompa(final Oompa_Loompa... Oompa_Loompa) {
    this(Oompa_Loompa, Oompa_Loompa);
  }
  Oompa_Loompa(final Oompa_Loompa[]... Oompa_Loompa) {
    this();
  }
  Oompa_Loompa Oompa_Loompa(final Oompa_Loompa Oompa_Loompa) {
    Oompa_Loompa: for (;;)
    for (;;)
           if (new Oompa_Loompa(Oompa_Loompa) { /*D*/
                @Override Oompa_Loompa Oompa_Loompa(final Oompa_Loompa Oompa_Loompa) {
                         return Oompa_Loompa != null ? /*C*/
                              super.Oompa_Loompa(Oompa_Loompa) /*B*/
                                :  Oompa_Loompa.this.Oompa_Loompa(Oompa_Loompa);
               }
            }.Oompa_Loompa(Oompa_Loompa) != null)
                break Oompa_Loompa;
             else
               continue Oompa_Loompa;
    return Oompa_Loompa;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code  is not valid Java. The line `Oompa_Loompa Oompa_Loompa;` makes no sense. So do others.

Comment: this is written in `Oompa_Loompa` not java

Comment: Too many Oompa_Loompas

Comment: I think OP just wants to know whether the `Oompa_Loompa` is being used as a `class name`, `variable name`, etc.

Comment: @AlexisP. A perfectly valid Java class.

Comment: No one sane writes such unreadable code. So it's ridiculous to try and read it.

Comment: "Super OompaLoompa with the question mark" is officially the greatest thing I have heard, or could hear, all day.

Comment: @Elazar Come on, you know it is not readable ^^

Comment: I'm guessing your teacher or professor wrote this?  This looks like the handy work of someone who codes but never for something actually used in anything.

Comment: For the heck of it I'm gonna attempt to answer. lol

Comment: I tried but I can't. Is this a new programming language?

Comment: I take the blame for composing the question. Students are to identify cases of hiding, overloading, polymorphic overloading, as well as the entities to which each occurrence of identifier `Oompa_Loompa` binds.
Students are encouraged to explore, and SO is a valid venue, as far as I am concerned. However, they are to write the answer themselves. So, should anyone care to answer, please leave it to the student(s) to compose the complete answers. Hints, and answers to subquestions (as posed above) are fine with me.

Comment: @YossiGil It's a shame you didn't choose `Bla` instead

Comment: Typical programmers' joke. Charlie, chocolate, etc. 
Had it been in Hebrew I would have used קונילמל. In Yiddish: 
קוני לעמל

Answer (score 2):

This: `super.Oompa_Loompa(Oompa_Loompa)` is an indirectly-recursive method call.

You pass the `Oompa_Loompa` variable of type `Oompa_Loompa` that the overriding `Oompa_Loompa` method got as a parameter, to the enclosing `Oompa_Loompa` method.

Here is a saner version:

```
class Klass {

    Klass field;

    <Type_Parameter> Klass() { }

    Klass(final Klass... param) {
        this(param, param);
    }

    Klass(final Klass[]... param) {
        this();
    }

    Klass method(final Klass param) {  // <------------------------\
        outer_loop:                                         //     |
        for (;;) {                                          //     |
            for (;;) {                                      //     |
                if (new Klass(param) {                      //     |
                    @Override                               //     |
                    Klass method(final Klass inner_param) { //     |
                        return inner_param != null          //     |
                             ? super.method(inner_param) // -------/
                             : Klass.this.method(inner_param);
                    }
                }.method(param) != null)
                    break outer_loop;
                else
                    continue outer_loop;
            }
        }
        return param;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you reffering to?

Comment: @AfikFriedberg I have added explanation

Comment: so can i use this method for hidding?

Comment: @AfikFriedberg I don't understand the question. Method names *can* hide constructor names. If you'd use eclipse or similar IDE you'll see easily what refers to what.

Comment: Why don't you use the course facebook group for such discussions?

https://www.facebook.com/groups/programming.languages/permalink/1066915873351591/?comment_id=1068194366557075&reply_comment_id=1068197379890107&notif_t=group_comment&notif_id=1459963775836787